# How to calculate $\lim_{x \to \infty}{\frac{1}{x}\int^{3x}_{x/3}} g(t) dt$?

Tags: integration, limits, continuity

Function $g: (0; +\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is unbounded, continous and has limit in $+\infty$ equal to $\pi$. How to calculate 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}{\frac{1}{x}\int^{3x}_{x/3}} g(t)\, dt?$$

Comment: "unbounded" is irrilevant, since can be unbounded only in a neighborhood of $0$, which is irrilevant, As for the question, you can approximate the integrand, in the limit, with $\pi$, so you obtain $\frac{1}{x}(3x-x/3)\pi=8\pi/3 $

Comment: @guestDiego Why can I do that?

Comment: Use the definition of limit: fix $\epsilon>0$ arbitrary. Then there exists $M_\epsilon>0$ such that for $x/3>M_\epsilon$, you have $|f(x)-\pi|<\epsilon$. So, for any $\epsilon>0$, you have that the limit is in the interval $[8(\pi-\epsilon)/3, 8(\pi+\epsilon)/3]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $g$ is continuous, by [mean value theorem for definite integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_Value_Theorems_for_Definite_Integrals) for $x>0$ $\exists\xi_x\in({x\over 3},3x):$
$$
\int_{x\over3}^{3x}g(t)dt=g(\xi_x)\left(3x-{x\over3}\right)\\
\implies{1\over x}\int_{x\over3}^{3x}g(t)dt={8\over3}g(\xi_x)
$$
$x\to+\infty\implies \xi_x\to+\infty\implies g(\xi_x)\to\pi$

So the required limit is ${8\pi\over3}$.